# Selenium thinks jQuery mobile element is invisible when it is visible on the page

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, jquery-mobile, mobile, selenium

I'm attempting to use Selenium 2.0 to automate the unit testing of a set of pages. Currently I navigate to the page and wait for all elements to be accessible. However it appears that due to jQuery Mobiles use of AJAX to load pages, the submit button on my page confuses Selenium because it thinks it is not visible.

The Selenium test I have is as follows:

```
        IWebElement page = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) => { return d.FindElement(By.Id("PostCode")); });
        IWebElement postCode = driver.FindElement(By.Id("PostCode"));
        IWebElement dob = driver.FindElement(By.Id("DOBPicker"));
        IWebElement maidenName = driver.FindElement(By.Id("MothersMaidenName"));
        IWebElement submit = driver.FindElement(By.Id("SubmitButton"));
        postCode.SendKeys("KA257EY");
        dob.SendKeys("1955-08-29");
        maidenName.SendKeys("onetwothreefour");
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("SubmitButton")));
        submit.Click();
```

The Selenium page fails on the wait.Until because it never seems to recognize that the button itself is visible.

The only other solution I have some up with is to implement something like this:

```
 IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
 js.ExecuteScript("$('#SubmitButton').click();");
```

However it appears that jQuery Mobile has something fancy going on here since the information it sends along with the post when the click originates from JS is different from an actual click by the user. This means that my page doesn't send the correct information in the post and the form submission is rejected by the server when the SubmitButton is clicked by JS and not the user.

Is there a way to force Selenium to recognize an element as visible?

Comment: Have you checked if there are multiple instances of #SubmitButton on the page?  It's possible Selenium is finding the first instance of that ID, and that instance is not visible.  You can check this fairly easily by printing driver.FindElements(By.Id("SubmitButton")).Count

Comment: I'm certain there are no other instances of SubmitButton on the page. Doing a lookup via jQuery only produces one instance of the element.

Comment: Try `$('#form_id').trigger('submit');` and maybe you need to add `data-ajax="false"` attribute to form div.

Comment: Omar, that actually worked out, can you make it an answer to this question so I can give you credit for it?

Comment: Though the jQuery workaround is fine, I'd say that shows there is a flaw somewhere. I would investigate exactly *how* your submit button is made visible/invisible (i.e what CSS styles, what Javascript) and then try to recreate it in a smaller web page, and submit it off to the Selenium guys. After all, if `.Visible` is returning false yet you can clearly see it on the page, isn't something *badly* wrong?

Comment: From what i can tell its a bug with the way that the page shows certain elements. jQuery mobile itself thinks that the items takes up no space on the page, so its not a fault of selenium but rather jQuery mobile. I've been investigating this issue quite thoroughly trying to discover the actual cause.

Comment: I forgot to mention something regarding showing hidden elements, you may try `$('#div id or page id').trigger('updatelayout');` after you show a hidden element. Try it, this could fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit form programmatically, upon button click or any other event.

```
$('#form_id').trigger('submit');
```

Also, if you want to submit form without using jQuery Mobile Ajax, add the below attribute to form div.

```
<form id="foo" data-ajax="false">
```

**References:**

1. [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)
2. [`data-ajax="false"`](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/#FileInputsAJAX)